# Scientific notation in Synapse

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

How i can convert this scientific notation in synpase ? thanks[image]

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried so far? errors/blockers? and sample data and expected result?

Comment: when I integrate an excel file there are a scientific notation like 49494E+11  , I would like in my converting sink that they no longer appear.  49494E+11 = 417188353374

Answer (score 0):

In the mapping section, you would have to explicitly map the column as decimal :
[image]

else it would consider it as string and copy it as E+11